# What does wsimport do with jax-ws-catalog.xml?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

All of the documentation I've found online about wsimport seems to be a little vague about one aspect of using a catalog file (jax-ws-catalog.xml). My question is:

When I generate a web service client using wsimport and the -catalog option, does wsimport only use my catalog **during build time** in order to find the WSDL it's using to create the web service? Or does it also somehow bundle the catalog into the generated web service so that the catalog can be used to locate resources during run time?

I'm guessing that wsimport only uses the catalog file to resolve resources during build time, and that if I want to use a catalog file to resolve resources at run time, that I have to bundle jax-ws-catalog.xml with my web client, but again, the documentation I've found so far seems a bit unclear, I'd prefer to hear this confirmed explicitly by someone who knows better.

**UPDATE:** I'm using a Maven plugin to generate my web service classes (http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html).

Let me know if anything in this question is unclear and I'll edit to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

@dbisdorf --> yes , when you use -catalog option the with *catalog.xml file , that file is copied over to the WEB-INF or META-INF dir of the Java EE project. This will be used to lookup refernece @ Runtine .If you don't wish to use it you should specify genRuntimeCatalog=false.

This is clearly documented in the following link : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/xml.html

Comment: @ArjanTijms : I'm not seeing the catalog file in the output directory where the generated classes appear. Also, I'm not using a Weblogic ANT task to generate my client; I'm using a Maven plugin that I reference in my pom.xml file. I've added a link to the documentation for the plugin in question. It doesn't state explicitly in this documentation whether the catalog file will or will not be included in the output of wsimport.

Comment: After running jax-wsimport with the -verbose flag, the output does not mention the catalog file at all.

Comment: @dbisdorf how about the -X option of maven ? does it give any information ?

Comment: No, running maven with -X still does not produce any output that mentions the catalog file. In my particular case it *appears* that the catalog is only being used to resolve resources at build time, and is not being bundled with the generated classes for use at runtime. I'm going to have to assume that this is the way that wsimport is functioning in this particular case.

Comment: It's not bundled with the generated java classes for me either, I'm pretty sure it is only used for finding wsdl.